# CMake Qt module disables exception handling

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, kde-plasma

My CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)

if (${QT4_FOUND})
    include(${QT_USE_FILE})
    include_directories(${QT_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)

if (${KDE4_FOUND})
    include(KDE4Defaults)
    include_directories(${KDE4_INCLUDE_DIR} ${KDE4_INCLUDES})
    link_directories(${KDE4_LIB_DIR})
endif ()
```

In the build process it says:

```
error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

I remember this issue sometime ago and I suspect Qt to add compile options but why?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you need to enable exceptions. You can add the flag with the next line in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions( -Wall -O2 -fexceptions )
```